# Откуда берёт значения getconf?

Tags: linux

При запуске getconf получаем список показателей и их значений. Например вот:

```
$ getconf -a
LINK_MAX                           65000
_POSIX_LINK_MAX                    65000
MAX_CANON                          255
_POSIX_MAX_CANON                   255
MAX_INPUT                          255
_POSIX_MAX_INPUT                   255
```

Вопрос: откуда он их берёт и возможно ли их изменить?

Comment: Попробуй setconf

Answer (score 2):

[`getconf`](http://manpages.org/getconf) в GNU/Linux — это часть libc и по сути является только лишь консольный интерфейс к библиотечным функциям [`sysconf`](http://ru.manpages.org/sysconf/3), [`pathconf`](http://ru.manpages.org/pathconf/3) и [`confstr`](http://ru.manpages.org/confstr/3).

Список переменных [жёстко задан](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/getconf.c.html#56) в самом `getconf`. Их значения в большинстве своём заданы при компиляции libc, хотя некоторые значения получаются на основе данных из `/proc`, `/sys` и системных вызовов, например [`getrlimit()`](http://ru.manpages.org/getrlimit/2) (размер стека косвенно определяет `ARG_MAX`) и [`sysinfo()`](http://ru.manpages.org/sysinfo/2) (определяет `_NPROCESSORS_CONF`).

> возможно ли их изменить?

Вообще говоря, нет. Хотя на некоторые (очень немногие) можно опосредованно повлиять, например на тот же `ARG_MAX` можно изменить задав меньший размер стека: `ulimit -s 4096`. А `_NPROCESSORS_CONF` можно изменить убрав или добавив ядра процессора. И, конечно, всегда можно внести изменения в libc и/или ядро linux и пересобрать их.

Answer (score 2):

Ессли читать доку

```
man 3 sysconf
```

то увидим:

```
Для параметров, как правило, используются константы  вида  _POSIX_FOO,  
которые  могут  быть определены  в  <unistd.h>.

Для переменных или ограничений, как правило,  используются  константы  вида  
_FOO,  возможно определённые  в <limits.h>, или _POSIX_FOO, возможно 
определённые в  <unistd.h>.
```